# Parse html and replace words by anchor tag

Tags: php

I need to replace all keywords by an anchor tag. But do not replace it if it is inside of a tag such as title,meta,bold,strong etc.

```
$keyword = "test";
 $pattern = "/".$keyword."(?!([^<]+)?>)/";
 $replacement  = "<a  style='color:red;'>".$keyword."</a>";         
 $text     = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $text );  
 echo $text;
```

It is replacing all words.For eg: title tag is coming with "Title test title". Don't replace it if it is coming with text like above. Is it possible to create an array pattern for checking whether the keyword is inside of a html tag and if it is then don't replace it.Can anybody help me. If any other option is there please give me.
Thanks,
Dixon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do using this way:

```
str_replace(
  array("meta", "title", "head"),
  array("<a style='color:red;'>meta</a>", "<a style='color:red;'>title</a>", "<a style='color:red;'>head</a>"),
  $string
);
```

This is one of the simplest ways to do if there are little keywords. You don't need a DOM Parser or Regex for this.

Comment: and meta, title, and/or head wold NEVER appear in anything other than a tag context...

Comment: I just said, check what OP has given. :) `title,meta,bold,strong`

Comment: It is replacing title tag. In your example if the the title is meta then it is replaced as an anchor tag. I want to disallow replacement in the rich html tags such as bold,strong,h1,h2 etc and other tags like title,head,meta etc.